# Laravel | Map one collection as property of another collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table like this:
[image]

`CourseCategory` can have duplicates in this table so that means a `courseCategory` can have multiple `courseNames`.

I am fetching all the `courseCategory` like this:

```
$courseCategories = Course::all()->pluck('courseCategory')->unique();
```

[image]

But Now I want to map all the courseNames beloging to a courseCategory in this collection.
**so that I can have a `$courseCategories` which I want to be able to access it like this:**

```
foreach($courseCategories as $courseCategory){
  foreach($courseCatgory->courseNames as name){
 //code 
 }
}
```

**to get such a `$courseCategories` So far I have tried:**

```
foreach ($courseCategories as $courseCategory) {

     $courseCategories->$courseCategory = Course::where('courseCategory', '=', $courseCategory)->pluck('courseName');

}
     dump($courseCategories);
```

which looks like this which is not quite right:

[image]

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all data

```
$data = Course::all()
```

Get its category

```
$categories = $data->pluck('courseCategory')->unique();
```

Then do some mapping and filtering to get each of those categories child.

```
$result = $categories->map(function($category) use ($data) { 
    return $data->filter(function($row) use ($category) { 
        return $category == $row->courseCategory; 
    })->pluck('courseName');  
});
```